# Importing Javascript errors

Tags: javascript, html, import

I'm trying to import simplex-noise.mjs file into main.mjs. I found on another stack overflow thread how to accomplish this, but I'm getting two errors.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

and

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

My functions and imports are

```
export function SimplexNoise() {
... do stuff ...
}
```

and

```
import { SimplexNoise } from 'simplex-noise';
```

Additionally, in my html I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="simplex-noise.mjs"></script>
```

I originally had the files as just .js, but I read that they should be .mjs (the same error persisted). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting `type` as `module`.

Comment: That changed the the export error (added new ones but I can look at them outside this post) but didn't fix the "unexpected token {" error. Thanks!